# Unable to access Google account in Android Market on HTC Desire HD

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

After resetting factory settings, I am not able to access my Google account in Gmail / Market / Talk. Whenever I try to "sign-in" to Android Market using Google account, it shows error with title as "Can't establish a reliable data connection to the server" and the message as "This could be a temporary problem or your phone may not be provisioned for data services. If it continues, call Customer Care."

What can I do to access "Android Market" from my HTC Desire HD? I'm using Bangladeshi net gp.

Comment: Backup your data and then do a reset. Hope it help you.

Comment: How are you accessing the market? 3G/Wifi?

Comment: have you tried to access the playstore site via the browser (to prove the server is reachable)? If that fails as well, there might be a routing problem -- or your provider blocks something.

Comment: Which Android version you have?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting their questions, and no answers have been upvoted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

This would indicate that you are not connected to the Internet.

When you did the factory reset, the APN data for your network/carrier might have been erased.

You will have to check with your network/carrier for the correct APN settings.

You can also connect to a wifi network to connect your Google Account.

You can enter the APN settings by going to `System Settings->Wireless and Networks->Mobile Networks->Access Point Names->Menu Button->Add New`.

Comment: no my internet setting is perfect. i can browse other sits. but cant access google account in market

Answer (score -3):

Try reinstalling [Google play services](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/).